¿Cómo van los rangos de las teclas del teclado en UNICODE?
Los Rangos de las teclas del Teclado en ASCII es de 0 a 255 pero
¿Cómo van los rangos de las teclas del teclado en UNICODE?
Tengo una función escrita en javascript que me escribe en el documento html la primera tanda de caracteres, números, símbolos, etc..., pero, sólo lo he puesto hasta 256 porque no se cual es el limite de UNICODE.
¿Hay más caracteres que pueda imprimir en el documento que sean relevantes para esto?
Agradezco sus respuestas.


function EscribeTeclas(){
    var i = 0;
    var Texto = "";
    for (i=32 ; i < 128 ; i++  ){
        var Caracter = "";
        Texto = "" + Texto + "Caracater: " + String.fromCharCode(i) + " Número:" + i + "<br>\n"; 
    }
    for (i=160 ; i < 256 ; i++  ){
        var Caracter = "";
        Texto = "" + Texto + "Caracater: " + String.fromCharCode(i) + " Número:" + i + "<br>\n"; 
    }
    
    document.write(Texto);
}




buena pregunta...

es en VB o en javascript ... define en donde se ejecuta el codigo por que pareciera javascript  ... ajajajjajaja

Los teclados no envían ASCII ni UNICODE. Cada vez que presionas o sueltas una tecla, se envía un código numérico (fijo por hardware) que identifica la acción (presionar o soltar) y la tecla (tecla 43). Cuando presionas "acento" y luego "a", el PC tiene que capturar la secuencia completa e interpretarla según el teclado que configuraste en el S.O. para informar al programa que escribiste "á". Es complicadito.

El rango de caracteres en Unicode es mucho más amplio que en ASCII. Mientras que ASCII solo cubre de 0 a 127 (extendido a 255 en ASCII extendido), Unicode abarca un rango que incluye más de 1.1 millones de puntos de código (hasta el código U+10FFFF: Límite). Sin embargo, los caracteres más utilizados están en el Plano Multilingüe Básico (BMP), que abarca de U+0000 a U+FFFF.
De los relevantes: Si deseas generar caracteres Unicode con JavaScript, puedes usar funciones como String.fromCharCode() (que funciona para los primeros 65,536 caracteres del BMP) o String.fromCodePoint() (para todo el rango Unicode).
Ahora puedo apoyarte con esta implementacion y utiliza String.fromCodePoint():
function EscribeTeclas() {
    let texto = "";
    // Ajusta los rangos de acuerdo con lo que quieres mostrar.
    // Del 32 al 255 (incluyendo caracteres Unicode extendidos básicos).
    for (let i = 32; i < 256; i++) {
        texto += `Carácter: ${String.fromCodePoint(i)} | Número: ${i} <br>\n`;
    }

    // Opcional: Explora un rango mayor dentro del BMP (ejemplo, emojis).
    for (let i = 0x1F600; i <= 0x1F64F; i++) { // Emojis "Smileys and Emotion".
        texto += `Carácter: ${String.fromCodePoint(i)} | Número: ${i.toString(16)} <br>\n`;
    }

    document.write(texto);
}

Documentacion utilizada:

https://unicode.org/
Documentación de String.fromCodePoint(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint


Los números del segundo ciclo que propones ¿Por donde empiezan y por donde acaban?. En hexadecimal no se entiende. A demás, el rango de 128 a 160 no lo quiero poner por ser cosas de sistema. ¿El rango entero de los emojis cual es?

todo eso lo puedes ver en la documentación... que agregue... como eso no lo preguntaste en el post original  no lo respondí...
